# Wondering why when I make a subset in python it is saying I have a empty dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, subset, pandas-loc

Trying to get different subsets of town names I have 18 towns and 2300 rows so i wanted to make different subsets of each town

Input -> dbqhomes = dbq.loc[dbq['town'] == 'DUBUQUE']
print(dbqhomes)

Output -> Empty DataFrame
Columns: [address, town, PropertyType, Sale Price, Sales_Type, Sale Date, Multi Sale, Year built, Lot area, Living area, Finished Basement Area, Basement type, Attic Type, Bedrooms, AC?, Fireplace?, Vacant?, Style, Assessed Value]
Index: []

Input -> dbqhomes.head()

Output -> just shows the Column names

Now I also have column where it says if the property type is a building or land and i did the same function above and it worked perfect my question would be is why is it saying Empty Data frame

Input -> buildingsubset = dbq.loc[dbq["PropertyType"] == 'Building']
print(buildingsubset)

Output -> printed every property

and

Input -> buildingsubset.head()
Output -> all columns and all rows that contained just the buildings which were around 1900

Comment: Could you show some of the data? Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Comment: This is my first time using stack overflow. I tried to send a picture however i don’t think it worked

Comment: Paste the dataframe in text format. See the link.